# Running .NET application on different machines

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, exe

So I've made a forms application with visual studio 2012 using .NET 4.5 framework. The application (exe) works fine only on my computer. I've tried two other computers to run it on but both seem not to be able to run it. I've installed .NET framework 4.5 on both the machines ofcourse. The error on the one is:

> To run this application, you must first install one of the following
>   versions of the .NET Framework:   v4.0.30319
>   Contact your
>   application publisher for instructions about obtaining the 
>   appropriate version of the .NET Framework.

And the other machine just brings up the windows error message which says that the application has stopped working.
Again, both computers have .NET framework 4.5 installed. I've also tried to install 4.0 to try but the installer says that a newer version is detected so I don't need to install this one (pretty obvious). 
I also tried to publish it so it'll generate a setup program to install prerequisite components, but again the setup works fine on my computer and doesn't even start on the other.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it have any dependency?

Comment: on the one with the windows error message look in the event viewer

Comment: can you config the target framework for your *exe* project is .net4.5 ? (and not .net4?) - also, can you paste the relevant section of your client app.config file, ie the `<startup>` element. My best guess is your app is indeed targetting 4.5 but you have the <startup> element targeting .net4 (via supportedRuntime element) and this works on your machine because you have both installed

Comment: This is what I've got in the app.config file in <startup> element: <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" /> So it looks like you're right, though how do I change it to 4.5? I assume I can't just change the xml right?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if the application requires .NET 4.0 you need to install it. My best guess is that you *think* the target is 4.5, but really it is not. Also, the target framework is specified in the `.exe.config` file. Maybe you should publish it along with the application.

Comment: Yes it seems like my startup element is specified for 4.0 in the .config. Do you know how do I change it to 4.5 via VS?

Comment: In the project properties, select a new target framework on the "Application" tab.